# Is there any way use gluon map for navigation or direction?

Tags: gluon, gluon-mobile

I'm integrating **gluon** maps in my application. I'm able to find location of two different users on the map. However, what I need is a  `direction/navigation` - feature like **google map** in **gluon mobile**. Is there any to obtain it?

Comment: Gluon Maps doesn't implement any direction/navigation feature, you will have to add it on top of it, using [`MapLayer`](https://github.com/gluonhq/maps/blob/master/maps/src/main/java/com/gluonhq/maps/MapLayer.java) to render JavaFX nodes.

Comment: But in order to render navigation or route I will need MapPoint between two locations. How to get all of the MapPoint in order to render route?

Comment: That is out of scope of Gluon Maps. You can find online services that will provide a routing API. For starters, check [this](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/87935/seeking-route-calculation-service-to-get-route-between-several-points).